# BCP converting DATE to VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I can't save file. I don't know why

```
DECLARE @allquery varchar(8000)

SET @allquery = ' bcp "SELECT ''a'' UNION ALL SELECT ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()as date) as char(200)) + ' FROM rozklad.dbo.rozklad" queryout D:\bcp\tmp.txt -S '+@@SERVERNAME+' -T -w -t,'

exec xp_cmdshell @allquery
```

I get this error

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to datatype int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some single quotes. Try this

```
DECLARE @allquery varchar(8000)
SET @allquery = ' bcp "SELECT ''a'' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE()as date) as char(200)) + ''' FROM rozklad.dbo.rozklad" queryout D:\bcp\tmp.txt -S '+@@SERVERNAME+' -T -w -t,'
exec xp_cmdshell @allquery
```

Your initial query was writing something like

```
SELECT 'a'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2016-03-24
```

This results in an error because 2016-03-24 results in 1989 which is an INT.

Now it will be like

```
SELECT 'a'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-03-24'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this part outside your quotes:

```
CAST(CAST(GETDATE()as date) as char(200))
```

It should be inside the quotes so it is evaluated by SQL.

```
"SELECT ''a'' UNION ALL SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE()as date) as char(200)) FROM ...
```

Also, you should consider a smaller size for your cast of date to char.  When would you have a result that's char(200) ?